# Requesting a finite trivial example with this family of sets and union is associative to help me prove

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, proof-explanation, intuition, associativity

[image]

May I have a finite example where we define what a, $\cup$S, $F_a$, and C  are? I think that would help for understanding this infinite proof. I don't see how this proof is true for finite examples of a, $\cup$S, $F_a$, and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $S$ is a system of sets, the notation $a\in \bigcup S$ is meaningful only if $a$ is a set; so $a$ is some element which must be in one or more of the sets in the system $S$. Then for each instance of $a$, $F_a$ is some set as well (which in general need not be in the system $S$), and $C$, ranging over the members of system $S$, takes on as values various sets, all of which are in $S$.

To give a finite example of these, let's work with the sets in $S$ being intervals on $\Bbb Z$ and take:
$$
S = \{ [5n,5n+2] :  n\in [1,3] \}\\
F_a = \{ ka^2 : k\in \Bbb Z \wedge (1\leq k \leq 4)\}
$$
Then
$$
a\in \bigcup S \Leftrightarrow a\in \{ 5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,17\}\\
F_5 = \{25,50,75,100\}\\
F_6 = \{36,72,108,144\}\\
\cdots\\
F_{17} = \{ 289,578,867,1156 \}
$$
and let's try out the union relation you are asked to prove:

It says that the union of all the elements of all the $F_a$s is equal to 
the union over the three sets in system $S$ (that is, $C$ takes on values $\{5,6,7\}$ then  $\{10,11,12\}$ then  $\{15,16,17\}$) of the sets formed by taking the union of all three $F_a$ for $a$ in the particular $C$ being considered.

That is,
$$
\{25,50,75,100\} \cup 
\{36,72,108,144\} \cup
\cdots \cup \{ 289,578,867,1156 \} \\
= (\{25,50,75,100\} \cup 
\{36,72,108,144\} \cup \{49,98,147,196\} ) \\ \cup
(\{100,200,300,400\} \cup 
\{121,242,363,484\} \cup \{144,288,432,576\} ) \\ \cup
(\{225,450,675,900\} \cup \{256,512,768,1024\} \cup \{ 289,578,867,1156 \})
$$

This is pretty trivially true; the gist of the problem is to prove it is true in general, including for infinite sets and infinite systems of sets without using any axioms that are unavailable in your logic/set theory.

Comment: is learning this stuff actually helpful for any math subject like algebra, real analysis, anything?

Comment: why doesn't which in general $F_a$ need to be in the system S?

Comment: How do you know $ F_a$ is a set?

Comment: What's the difference between a system of sets and some power set or set of sets of sets....? What the formal definition of a system of sets?

Comment: do we need the axiom of choice?

Comment: this sounds familiar, I think in computer science you take the union of an very large number of family of sets so at last 10 unions of union of unions... cs is like applied set theory where you're expected to compute all the near infinitely large unions in your head.

Comment: @Chris This fact implies that a countable union of $F_\sigma$ sets in a topological space is again an $F_\sigma$, e.g.

Comment: So one union is equal to the union of union or two unions. Can a union equal three unions, 4, 5... n unions? Then we'd need more indexed families of sets? If we increase the number of indexed families of sets from 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 to n...., can we have one union equal to the union of the union of the union of the union......?

Comment: Why isn't the proof given in my answer done by induction? I think we've shown the the union of two indexed families of sets is associative or we expressed a single union as two unions and made everything redundant. Can we show by induction mathematical that a single union can be expressed as 3 unions, 4 unions, n-unions rather than just 2 unions? Also can a di-union, the right hand side of the conclusion of the proof given my in question be expressed as a k-union, where $ k>2$ union by induction? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: If there is a direct proof, don't bother with induction. It would also be restrictive @Chris